# Why does not cf push "appname" update files in IBM Bluemix?

Tags: node.js, ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry

I run `cf push appname`, have made changes to `server.js` but after successful push, I check the files in Bluemix, via runtime, my changes are not there?

uk-region

commands;

```
cf login -u email -o email -s dev

cf push appname
```

Cloud Foundry app called rest-hgc

Help please?

Comment: Add more details, which steps, which Bluemix region, ...

Comment: UK-Region

I use to develop locally and do the follwoing;

cf login -u email -o emal -s dev
cf push appname

Comment: Added info in the question.

Comment: Is your server.js file in the same directory you run `cf push`? If it is make sure this local file has the changes before you push application again.

Comment: Yes, it is in the project directory where I was running the commands. I will do, I will also step out of Webstorm, I do think it may cause a problem with it own history cache.

Comment: It does it help. It is the same old server.js file.

Can I clear caches or something like that via cf commands?

Comment: Actually, I removed a console.log from the server.js and that is not displayed in the log f´så it must be the web interface in Bluemix that does not pick up correct files when I want to look at them. :-)

Comment: You can always use `cf files` on BlueMix to check the files in the actual running application. Can you please answer your own question, so other readers can benefit from what you have learnt?

Comment: Thanks for the command, did not know about it. Have posted an answer to my own question now. Would like to get feedback so my reputation rank gets higher. :-)

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to not be a problem with the actual command to push the app to Bluemix runtime.

Instead it must be a problem with the web interface of Bluemix, not picking up the latest files when trying to view them.

After I logged in to Bluemix, to the left there is a new menu. I click on Apps - Dashboard and get a list of my Cloud Foundry apps and services. I click on one of my Cloud Foundry apps - I get a new menu where I click on Runtime.

In the main area, I have a new tab meny, Memory Instances, Environment Variables, and Files.

I click on Files and navigate within my app to locate the server.js file.

What I can see there is not matching what I did push, so I think there is a bug or something.

Comment: Can you explain in more detail? What screen on Bluemix are you using to view your files?